# ViewState vs ViewData in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between viewstate and viewdata in mvc?

Answer (score 2):

I was just going through the MVC framework & the exact question popped up in my head.. I understand the difference as below.

ASP.Net & MVC are two different worlds. But looking closely they are not. The concepts of web remains the same and it just the way to write the code. Ok letz compare them

**ASP.Net**
.aspx    -- So this is the view which contains the html to be rendered in the browser

.aspx.cs -- as we know this is the code behind for doing all the manipulation of the html

So on top of that we have the BO with our properties and which is bound to the controls using databind.

So here comes the ViewState which remembers the data bound to the controls back and forth between the postback.

**MVC**
View - this holds all the HTML code which in turn is still a .aspx or ascx file

Controller - has the logic behind the HTML. Inside that you have the action methods for performing the specific actions.

So here instead of BO, you have the Models with the same properties which is given to the View to render itself in a different syntax instead of a databind.

Now ViewData is used to bind the anonymous data between the controller and the view.

Comparatively ViewData is more organized and easy to use but apart from that they serve a similar purpose but different in few ways. Like Viewstate is persistent between postbacks and ViewData is not as MVC is stateless.

Hope this explains to an extent

Answer (score 1):

ViewState and ViewData can handle some complex objects.

ViewState is within page lifecycle while ViewData works in very different way. ViewData can be passed to the target view.

Please refer here for understanding of viewState:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

for viewData:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

View state is used only in ASP.net forms,controls and Page life cycle. View state is used by ASP.net framework to manage control states.

View Data is a dataset or Data which is passed to your View - to dipslay HTML data in MVC,

Viewstate is not used in MVC. Please refer above mentioned links for more details.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx